# Django - (Tagulous) AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn as much as possible myself with regards to discovering solutions to my challenges, but this error has got me stuck a little! (I am currently trying to implement Tagulous in to my app)

At the point of running a migration, I am receiving the following error:

AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '_meta'

Here is the code I have implemented so far whilst referencing the Tagulous tutorials

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image
import tagulous.models



class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='media')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content[:5]

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    @property
    def number_of_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(post_connected=self).count()

class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_connected = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Preference(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post= models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value= models.IntegerField()
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ':' + str(self.post) +':' + str(self.value)

    class Meta:
       unique_together = ("user", "post", "value")
       
class Skill(tagulous.models.TagTreeModel):
    class TagMeta:
        initial = [
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
        ]
        space_delimiter = False
        autocomplete_view = "swaptags_skills_autocomplete"


class SwapTags(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title = tagulous.models.SingleTagField(
        initial="test1, test2",
        help_text=(
            "This is a SingleTagField - effectively a CharField with " "dynamic choices"
        ),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    skills = tagulous.models.TagField(
        Skill, help_text="This field does not split on spaces"
    )
    hobbies = tagulous.models.TagField(
        initial="eating, coding, gaming",
        force_lowercase=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="This field splits on spaces and commas",
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "swaptags"
```

Views.py

```
class SwapTagsView(ListView):
    swaptags = models.SwapTags.objects.all()
    titles = models.SwapTags.title.tag_model.objects.all()
    skills = models.Skill.objects.all()
    hobbies = models.SwapTags.hobbies.tag_model.objects.all()

    if swaptags_pk:
        swaptags = models.SwapTags.objects.get(pk=swaptags_pk)
        submit_label = "Update"
    else:
        person = None
        submit_label = "Add"

    if request.POST:
        swaptags_form = forms.SwapTagsForm(request.POST, instance=swaptags)
        if swaptags_form.is_valid():
            swaptags = swaptags_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Form saved as SwapTags %d" % swaptags.pk)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(index))
    else:
        swaptags_form = forms.SwapTagsForm(instance=swaptags)

    return render(
        request,
        "sfsrv/post_new.html",
        {
            "title": "SwapTag Name",
            "SwapTags_name": models.SwapTags.__name__,
            "Title_name": models.SwapTags.title.tag_model.__name__,
            "Skill_name": models.Skill.__name__,
            "Hobby_name": models.SwapTags.hobbies.tag_model.__name__,
            "swaptags": swaptags,
            "titles": titles,
            "hobbies": hobbies,
            "skills": skills,
            "swaptags_form": swaptags_form,
            "form_media": swaptags_form.media,
            "submit_label": submit_label,
        },
    )
```

**forms.py (Updated)**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment
from sfsrv.models import SwapTags
import tagulous.models


class NewCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content']

class SwapTagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["name", "title", "skills", "hobbies"]
        model = SwapTags
```

**Traceback representing error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/*/sfsrv/admin.py", line 17, in <module>
    tagulous.admin.register(models.Model, SwapTagsAdmin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagulous/admin.py", line 316, in register
    singletagfields = tag_models.singletagfields_from_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagulous/models/fields.py", line 526, in singletagfields_from_model
    return [field for field in model._meta.fields if isinstance(field, SingleTagField)]
AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '_meta'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/*/sfsrv/admin.py", line 17, in <module>
    tagulous.admin.register(models.Model, SwapTagsAdmin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagulous/admin.py", line 316, in register
    singletagfields = tag_models.singletagfields_from_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagulous/models/fields.py", line 526, in singletagfields_from_model
    return [field for field in model._meta.fields if isinstance(field, SingleTagField)]
AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '_meta'
```

**0001_initial.py (Migration)**

```
 operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="_Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.AutoField(
                        verbose_name="ID",
                        serialize=False,
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                    ),
                ),
                ("name", models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)),
                ("slug", models.SlugField()),
                (
                    "count",
                    models.IntegerField(
                        default=0,
                        help_text="Internal counter of how many times this tag is in use",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "protected",
                    models.BooleanField(
                        default=False,
                        help_text="Will not be deleted when the count reaches 0",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={"ordering": ("name",), "abstract": False},
            bases=(tagulous.models.models.BaseTagModel, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="_Tagulous_SwapTags_title",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.AutoField(
                        verbose_name="ID",
                        serialize=False,
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                    ),
                ),
                ("name", models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)),
                ("slug", models.SlugField()),
                (
                    "count",
                    models.IntegerField(
                        default=0,
                        help_text="Internal counter of how many times this tag is in use",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "protected",
                    models.BooleanField(
                        default=False,
                        help_text="Will not be deleted when the count reaches 0",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={"ordering": ("name",), "abstract": False},
            bases=(tagulous.models.models.BaseTagModel, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="SwapTags",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.AutoField(
                        verbose_name="ID",
                        serialize=False,
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                    ),
                ),
                ("name", models.CharField(max_length=255)),
                (
                    "hobbies",
                    tagulous.models.fields.TagField(
                        force_lowercase=True,
                        initial="eating, coding, gaming",
                        to="example._Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies",
                        blank=True,
                        help_text="This field splits on spaces and commas",
                        _set_tag_meta=True,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={"verbose_name_plural": "swaptags"},
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="Skill",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.AutoField(
                        verbose_name="ID",
                        serialize=False,
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                    ),
                ),
                ("name", models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)),
                ("slug", models.SlugField()),
                (
                    "count",
                    models.IntegerField(
                        default=0,
                        help_text="Internal counter of how many times this tag is in use",
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "protected",
                    models.BooleanField(
                        default=False,
                        help_text="Will not be deleted when the count reaches 0",
                    ),
                ),
                ("path", models.TextField()),
                (
                    "label",
                    models.CharField(
                        help_text="The name of the tag, without ancestors",
                        max_length=255,
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "level",
                    models.IntegerField(
                        default=1, help_text="The level of the tag in the tree"
                    ),
                ),
                (
                    "parent",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        related_name="children",
                        blank=True,
                        to="example.Skill",
                        null=True,
                        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            options={"ordering": ("name",), "abstract": False},
            bases=(tagulous.models.models.BaseTagTreeModel, models.Model),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="swaptags",
            name="skills",
            field=tagulous.models.fields.TagField(
                to="example.Skill",
                autocomplete_view="swaptags_skills_autocomplete",
                space_delimiter=False,
                help_text="This field does not split on spaces",
                _set_tag_meta=True,
                initial="test1, test2, test3",
                tree=True,
            ),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name="swaptags",
            name="title",
            field=tagulous.models.fields.SingleTagField(
                initial="eating, coding, gaming",
                force_lowercase=True,
                blank=True,
                to="example._Tagulous_SwapTags_title",
                help_text="This is a SingleTagField - effectively a CharField with dynamic choices",
                _set_tag_meta=True,
                null=True,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            ),
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name="_tagulous_swaptags_title", unique_together=set([("slug",)])
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name="_tagulous_swaptags_hobbies", unique_together=set([("slug",)])
        ),
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name="skill", unique_together=set([("slug", "parent")])
        ),
    ]
```

**tagulous_migration_0002.py (Migration)**

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("sfsrv", "0001_initial")]

    atomic = False

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name="_Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies", new_name="Tagulous_SwapTags_hobbies"
        ),
        migrations.RenameModel(
            old_name="_Tagulous_SwapTags_title", new_name="Tagulous_SwapTags_title"
        ),
    ]
```

**admin.py (UPDATED)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from tagulous.models import TagModel
from django.db import models
import tagulous.admin
from sfsrv.models import Post, Comment, Preference, SwapTags, Skill

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Preference)

# Register the SwapTags with a custom ModelAdmin
class SwapTagsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "title", "skills", "hobbies")
    list_filter = ("name", "title", "skills", "hobbies")

tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags, SwapTagsAdmin)

# Auto-gen the ModelAdmins for skills and hobbies
tagulous.admin.register(Skill)
tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags.hobbies.tag_model)


# Give the Title ModelAdmin the people as inlines
class SwapTagsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SwapTags
    extra = 3


class TitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SwapTagsInline]


tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags.title.tag_model, TitleAdmin)
```

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Thank you! :-) (If there is any other files you should need to see, do let me know!)

Comment: Can you show your migrations as well as the full traceback to the error? Which Django version are you using?

Comment: Hey GwynBleidD, thank you for your response! I am currently using Django 3.2.2 and sure. I will update my original question in a few minutes with a traceback of the error. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to register the Django `Model` class directly in your admin interface:

```
tagulous.admin.register(models.Model, SwapTagsAdmin)
```

You  can only register a subclass of a `Model`, not the class directly.

Comment: Hi there! Ah I totally missed this,   i've updated this to `tagulous.admin.register(models.SwapTags, SwapTagsAdmin)` to which I'm receiving a similar error `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SwapTags'`

Comment: Models is imported from `django.db`, not from your application models. Correct your imports and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you GwynBleidD, much appreciated! Imports are corrected and the issue has disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models.py is in app named **App**

Make changes in your **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from App.models import SwapTags

class SwapTagsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["name", "title", "skills", "hobbies"]
        model = SwapTags
```

Replace **App** on line 2 with your app name (whatever it is).

Update your
**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from tagulous.models import TagModel
from sfsrv.models import Post, Comment, Preference, SwapTags, Skill

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Comment)
admin.site.register(Preference)

# Register the SwapTags with a custom ModelAdmin
class SwapTagsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "title", "skills", "hobbies")
    list_filter = ("name", "title", "skills", "hobbies")


tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags, SwapTagsAdmin)

# Auto-gen the ModelAdmins for skills and hobbies
tagulous.admin.register(Skill)
tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags.hobbies.tag_model)


# Give the Title ModelAdmin the people as inlines
class SwapTagsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SwapTags
    extra = 3


class TitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SwapTagsInline]


tagulous.admin.register(SwapTags.title.tag_model, TitleAdmin)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response! I have implemented the above solution but still receiving the same error: AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Can you please update your question with sfsrv/admin.py
`tagulous.admin.register(models.Model, SwapTagsAdmin)`
Here it should be model name, not `models.Model`
But will take a look at admin.py before any final comment.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the contents of my admin.py file, thank you! :)

Comment: Ah thank you for spotting that - , i've updated this to `tagulous.admin.register(models.SwapTags, SwapTagsAdmin)` to which I'm receiving a similar error `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SwapTags'`

Comment: Consider updating your admin.py , I have updated my answer 
One more thing You have imported TagModel but haven't used anywhere in admin.py

Comment: Ah thank you Prakhar, that has got rid of that error! I will update my admin.py as you have suggested. I'm stuck with the following error within my Views.py: `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` which I know is usually caused by an Indentation issue, I have just double checked this line, and it appears to be indented correctly so I will have a little play around to see if I can get to the bottom of why this error is being returned.

Comment: All other errors have now been fixed at my side after a little more research and Tagulous is now working! Thank you for all your help and to others on here who have contributed with their responses!